# Principal object is anonymous JAAS security

Tags: java, security, jboss, jaas

Is it possible to set manually the `Principal` object in `SessionContext` ? for prototyping reasons, I'm validating the user credential against 3rd party system  then I want to set the authenticated user in Ejb context , 
I use JAAS custom login module just to set the principal object and fetch user's roles 
`SessionContext.getCallerPrincipal.getName()` always returns `ANONYMOUS`

Answer (score 2):

In EJB if the user didn't authenticate, you get a container specific principal with a container specific name. This is a bit annoying. Some containers allow you to set the anonymous Principal via some container specific mechanism.